# How to detect If user is Logged in the Facebook from native OS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, social-framework, acaccountstore

Is there a way to check if the user is signed in in the device settings?
If yes, how?

Also, is there a way to direct the user to the device settings directly to the Facebook account tab? If yes, how?

The thing is, I want to detect if the user is already logged in in the device settings. If yes, then I will let the user share. If not, I want to redirect the user to the device settings in the fb tab and let him decide if he wants to log in or not.

Comment: Yes you can check. But there is no way to direct the user in Facebook tab under the settings. In fact it is not possible to open settings from your app via programmatically

Comment: I see, so even if I can detect, there's now ay to direct my user to the settings. This means that I cannot do what I initially plan to do. Thank you so much for the fast reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if([SLComposeViewController instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(isAvailableForServiceType)] != nil)
{
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [composeViewController setInitialText:@"Hello"];
        [composeViewController setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

            switch (result) {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    [UIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:APPNAME message:@"Facebook sharing canceled!!"];
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    [UIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:APPNAME message:@"Successfully posted on Facebook."];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];
        [[self.window rootViewController] presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType;
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
NSArray *facebookAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
```

Comment: I tried this. it's always returning no even if i'm signed in on the device settings. Is there any idea why?